# Show the Product details by click the Product image using PHP and My SQL

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, database

all the product details will be stored by Category wise.

**for eg.** Nokia Category , Samsung Category

if i add product with nokia Category it will store the image as

```
imgupload/CategoryImage/1/orginal/image.jpg
```

here the "1 folder" will be nokia and same "2 folder" will be samsung. These folder numbers will be assigned by itself using *"id"*

My problem is I am not able to get the *"Category Id"* from the image link

```
<img src="imgupload/CategoryImage/<?php echo $catId; ?>/orginal/<?php echo $catImageName; ?> ">
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_GET['id']))
            {
                $id     =   $_GET['id'];
                $categoryImageModel =   new CategoryImageModel();                 
                $result = $categoryImageModel->categoryImageSelect("status=1 AND id='$id'",'id','ASC','');
                $row        =   mysql_fetch_array($result);
                $count      =   mysql_num_rows($result);
                $id         =   $row['id'];
                $catImageName       =   $row['imageName'];
                $imageTitle         =   $row['imageTitle'];
                $price              =   $row['price'];
                $description        =   $row['description'];    
            }        
            ?>          
         <img src="imgUploads/categoryImage/<?php echo $catId; ?>/original/<?php echo $catImageName; ?>" />
```

this line only the main problem. the category id not getting in the image path.
all the product details will be stored by Category wise.

Comment: can you show database tables ?

Comment: Where are you defining the `$catId` variable?

Comment: @Dhruv here the link to view Database table          https://drive.google.com/a/univercellmobile.co.in/file/d/0B3oBE5x-cNDwTktmMFE1WGdzOEk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @aphextwix I don't know how to use the two id call function "$cadID [Category id] " and "$id [Product id]" at same time, I only use the Product id [ $id ] can you help me to call both "id"  <a href="radnus-product-details.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"> View Details </a>     when i click this link it will come to above page and get the id request for view details

Comment: You need to define `$catId` before you can call it, i.e. `$catId = 'something';`. Where are you defining this?

Comment: @aphextwix thanks for your help now i solved my problem, i used this line in my codeing   $catId = $_REQUEST['catId']; now it works well once again thanks for replying. Please submit your answer in the "Answer your Question" i will rate it:)

Comment: Ok - have done below. Glad you fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem that you're having is that you haven't defined the `$catId` variable, you will need to assign some value to the variable like so :

```
$catId = 'something';
```